cannot load fine tuned fasttext wiki model after retraining and saving
I am fine tuning a fastest wiki model as follows. This works fine. After fine tuning I save the retrained model.
from gensim.models import fasttext
model = fasttext.load_facebook_model(datapath("wiki/wiki.en.bin"))
model.build_vocab(sentences, update=True)
model.train(sentences, total_examples=len(sentences), epochs=5)
model.save("wiki/wiki.en.updated.bin")

Later on when I try and load the model
model = fasttext.load_facebook_model(datapath("wiki/wiki.en.updated.bin")

I get an error
NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
Which is strange since I am not doing supervised training!?!? Any idea why this is happening and how to correctly load the fine tuned model?
Is impossible I am saving or loading the file wrong. I did notice that more than one file is created upon save, but that's just normal due to the underlying representation, or no?
I am running macOS 14.3 on an M2 Mac.
-rw-r--r--@ 1 sail0r  staff  8493673445 Oct 19  2017 wiki.en.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 sail0r  staff    84876251 Apr 14 02:12 wiki.en.updated.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 sail0r  staff  3023571728 Apr 14 02:12 wiki.en.updated.bin.syn1neg.npy
-rw-r--r--  1 sail0r  staff  2400000128 Apr 14 02:11 wiki.en.updated.bin.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy
-rw-r--r--  1 sail0r  staff  3023571728 Apr 14 02:11 wiki.en.updated.bin.wv.vectors_vocab.npy
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 sail0r  staff  6597238061 Sep 19  2016 wiki.en.vec

This is gensim 4.3.2.

This change to the code above fixes the problem.
from gensim.models import FastText, fasttext
model = FastText.load(datapath("wiki/wiki.en.bin"))

It seems that the retrained model is not saved in fasttext format and so just requires the load() method, otherwise apparently it gets confused.

Yes, the paired .save() and .load() methods on Gensim models use a Gensim-specific (Python pickle-based) format that's efficient for its needs, and may split the model over multiple files. If you need to save the model in the original Facebook code single- file format, use .save_facebook_model(). But if you use plain .save(), you need to load with .load(). (I think the Gensim format will save and load a little faster, and on load you have the mmap=True option that could be useful in some contexts.)
